# Tronweb and Trongrid Error: Request failed with status code 502

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, solidity

I'm using TronWeb and TronGrid when i try start somehow i see randomly completing index.js and sometimes it's completed with error. Status code 502..

```
PS D:\trontest> node index.js
balance: 6816.72342
PS D:\trontest> node index.js
(node:8144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 502
    at createError (D:\trontest\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (D:\trontest\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\trontest\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:8144) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
PS D:\trontest> node index.js
balance: 6816.72342
PS D:\trontest>
```

index.js

```
const TronGrid = require("trongrid");
const TronWeb = require("tronweb");

const tronWeb = new TronWeb({
    fullHost: 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io'
});

const tronGrid = new TronGrid(tronWeb);
const address = "TE5KZD*******EdwZYJqxWjqjAovvEeGu";

async function  getBalance(adr)  {
    const balance = await tronWeb.trx.getBalance(adr);
    console.log("balance:", balance/1000000);
}
getBalance(address);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "trontest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "trongrid": "^1.2.6",
    "tronweb": "^3.2.6"
  }
}
```

What i should to do to every request finished correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue. 1) Copy-pasted the `index.js` and `package.json`. 2) Run `npm i`. 3) Replaced the address for a [random address](https://tronscan.org/#/address/TYUsQ4RBZ7558wadJPmXibdo8Sy7FkBxnz) from the blockchain explorer. 4) Run `node index.js`. Output is `balance: 0`

Comment: @PetrHejda try few times send node index.js per and you show this problem) if you tried once you dont see it...

Comment: After multiple tries, I got the error. I don't know the solution right now, but it seems like a rate limit with incorrect response from the server (502 instead of 429).

Comment: @PetrHejda interesting...

Answer (score 0):

You have not put any API-KEY in your tronWeb instance. As a result, you have a very low query/ transaction per second. That might be reason why sometimes your transactions work and sometimes they don't

Answer (score 0):

```
const HttpProvider = TronWeb.providers.HttpProvider;
const fullNode = new HttpProvider("https://api.shasta.trongrid.io");
const solidityNode = fullNode;
const eventServer = fullNode;
const privateKey  = "475b583cc8ac2ed**********************3fb2";
const tronWeb = new TronWeb(fullNode,solidityNode,eventServer,privateKey);
const address = "TE5KZD*******EdwZYJqxWjqjAovvEeGu";
const trxBalance =(await tronWeb.trx.getBalance(address)) / 10 ** 6;
```

on top of the file import
`const TronWeb = require("tronweb");`

More reference :: **[CLICK HERE](https://developers.tron.network/reference/getbalance)**